# Code to populate lookup doesn't fully work first time

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I have some javascript code on my form that when the record is first being created it auto populates 2 lookup fields with the current user. This works fine most of the time but I've noticed that on the first time that I use it (per day/session?) the first field that I want to fill in does get populated however the field still looks empty, as if the code has not worked.

I've confirmed that the field is getting filled in and it is only the display for this field that isn't working, but I can't figure out why, especially why it is only the one field that this is happening with.

I will post the code I use below, when calling it I pass in an array of the field names that I want to set. Can anyone help me find out why this isn't working?

Thanks

```
function RetrieveUserInfo(fieldsToSet) {

//Retrieve user information
var context;
var serverUrl;
var UserID;
var ODataPath;

context = Xrm.Page.context;
serverUrl = context.getServerUrl();
UserID = context.getUserId();
ODataPath = serverUrl + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc";

var retrieveUserReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
retrieveUserReq.open("GET", ODataPath + "/SystemUserSet(guid'" + UserID + "')", true);
retrieveUserReq.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
retrieveUserReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

retrieveUserReq.onreadystatechange = function () {
    SetUserValues(this, fieldsToSet);
};

retrieveUserReq.send();
```

}

```
function SetUserValues(retrieveUserReq, fieldsToSet) {

if (retrieveUserReq.readyState == 4
/* complete */
) {
    if (retrieveUserReq.status == 200) {
        var retrievedUser = this.parent.JSON.parse(retrieveUserReq.responseText).d;
        if (retrievedUser.FullName != null)

        //Get details of current user
        var setUservalue = new Array();
        setUservalue[0] = new Object();
        setUservalue[0].id = Xrm.Page.context.getUserId();
        setUservalue[0].entityType = 'systemuser';
        setUservalue[0].name = retrievedUser.FullName;

        //get form type
        var formType = Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType();

        if (formType != undefined) { //Create
            if (formType == 1) {

                //for each field specified, set it to the current user
                for (var i = 0; i < fieldsToSet.length; i++) {
                    Xrm.Page.getAttribute(fieldsToSet[i]).setValue(setUservalue);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: seems like js loading priority issue

Comment: How can I get around this issue?

Comment: have you tried document.onload?

Comment: What fields are you trying to set custom or system?

Comment: They are both custom fields. I haven't tried that, is there an example of it around?

Comment: I'm assuming this is errors at the beginning of the day for each client, not just one error at the beginning of the day for all clients?

Comment: How did you confirm that the both fields are set but only only one displays the change?

Comment: Daryl - Yeah it is per client, I've tried it for a couple different users.

Comment: Konrad - I put an alert on to display the value of the field which showed that there was a value in it. And before that i had simply tried to save the record and it was then that it displayed the field as completed

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot, but the field that doesn't work - it doesn't happen to be a disabled field? If it's a *readonly* field you might have to add

```js
Xrm.Page.getAttribute(“fieldname”).setSubmitMode(“always”);
```

on the `onsave` event.

Comment: Its definitely enabled, as I am able to manually set the field to a different user if I want to